# Im trying to convert my encryption in C# into PHP

Tags: c#, php

I'm new to php and currently i'm trying to convert C# code to php,

Here my PHP code that i've tried

```
function cryptECB($crypt, $key) {
       //$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_3DES, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
         //$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        // crypting  
        $byteskey = "";
        for($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($key, 'ASCII'); $i++)
        {
           $byteskey .= ord($key[$i]);
        }

        $buffer = "";
        for($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($crypt, 'ASCII'); $i++)
        {
           $buffer .= ord($crypt[$i]);
        }

        $cryptText = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $byteskey, $buffer, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        return BytesToStr($cryptText);
}

function BytesToStr($data)
    {
        $value = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); $i++)
        {
            $value .= (String)$data[i];
        }
        return $value;
    }
```

Here is C# that i want to convert

```
public string DES3Encrypt(string data, string key)
        {
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
            DES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            ICryptoTransform DESEncrypt = DES.CreateEncryptor();
            byte[] Buffer = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            return BytesToStr(DESEncrypt.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length));
            //return Convert.ToBase64String(DESEncrypt.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length));
        }

public string BytesToStr(byte[] b)
        {
            string value = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
            {
                value += b[i].ToString("X2");
            }
            return value;
        }
```

i expect the same result, but it doesn't. how to do it correctly in php?

Comment: That code is not written in Java, looks more like C#

Comment: sorry, my mistake. i've changed it. thanks

Comment: If you could provide an example of the C# input and output, for those of us who know PHP but don't have the environment to code in C#.

At least that way, anyone trying to complete the PHP code, doesn't have to worry about finding out the C# equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [`mcrypt_encrypt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) is deprecated. Better use [`openssl_encrypt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php). Another advantage: `openssl_encrypt` and `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider` in the C#-code both use [PKCS7-padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) by default (`mcrypt_encrypt` uses Zero-Byte-padding).
- The built-in `bin2hex` in PHP corresponds to the `BytesToStr` in the C#-code.
- `openssl_encrypt` expects key and data as string.
- Thus, the code is simply:

  ```
  function cryptECB($plaintext, $key) {
      //$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, 'DES-EDE', $key,  OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);  // 16-byte key
      $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, 'DES-EDE3', $key,  OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);   // 24-byte key
      return bin2hex($ciphertext);
  }
  ```
- Note 1: [Triple-DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) can be used with different keying options. The C#-code supports the key sizes 16 bytes and 24 bytes, where the key size determines implicitly the respective keying option. **In contrast, in the PHP-code, the specified cipher-method determines the keying option**, i.e. for a 16-byte key the `DES-EDE` cipher-method must be used and for a 24-byte key the `DES-EDE3` cipher-method. If `DES-EDE3` is used for a 16-byte key, the key is extended to a 24-byte key by appending 0-values. And vice versa, if `DES-EDE` is used for a 24-byte key, the key is shortened to a 16-byte key by truncating the right side. Both would lead to results other than the C#-code!
- Note 2: If possible, ECB should not be used because it is [insecure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20941/why-shouldnt-i-use-ecb-encryption). Also, AES should be used instead of Triple-DES, see [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26179/security-comparsion-of-3des-and-aes).